# Is SystemVerilog string manipulation synthesisable?

Tags: fpga, system-verilog

I learnt that SystemVerilog provides a [string datatype](http://openesl.org/systemverilog-wiki/String_Type), which allows for many string operations, such as comparison, concatenation, length, etc.

Are those string operations synthesisable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, hardly anything in SystemVerilog is synthesisable; it's intended for use in testbenches and simulations.

Comment: This is not exactly true: "As of 2009, the SystemVerilog and Verilog language standards were merged into SystemVerilog 2009 (IEEE Standard 1800-2009)." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog).  So SystemVerilog is meant to be the new verilog, but with substantive extensions in verification.